# C: Ampersand in front of a number

Tags: c

What does this line (x = n & 5;) mean in the code below? As far as I know ampersand is used for pointers. I was not expecting this code to compiled, but it compiled and ran fine. The results I got is

> 0,1,0,1,4,5,4,5,0,1,

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    int x, n;
    for (n = 0; n < 10; n++){
        x = n & 5;
        printf("%d,", x);
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I compiled using gcc -W -Wall -pedantic -std=c89 ctest.c

Comment: It's an operator. Open your introductory C++ textbook and read it until you're familiar with the language basics.

Comment: Sorry, I had a long day. Can't believe I forgot about it. I even used it before.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this case it's bitwise AND.

```
x = n & 5;
```

will AND 5 (which is 0b101) with whatever is in `n`.

AND works on the bits that represent the values. The result will have a 1 if both values have a 1 in that position, 0 otherwise.

Since we're ANDing with 5, and there are only 4 values you can make with the two bits in 0b101, the only possible values for x are 1, 4, 5 and 0. Here's an illustration:

```
n           &    5     = x
1 (0b0001)  &  0b0101  = 1  (0b0001)
2 (0b0010)  &  0b0101  = 0  (0b0000)
3 (0b0011)  &  0b0101  = 1  (0b0001)
4 (0b0100)  &  0b0101  = 4  (0b0100)
5 (0b0101)  &  0b0101  = 5  (0b0101)
6 (0b0110)  &  0b0101  = 4  (0b0100)
7 (0b0111)  &  0b0101  = 4  (0b0100)
8 (0b1000)  &  0b0101  = 0  (0b0000)
9 (0b1001)  &  0b0101  = 1  (0b0001)
```

Answer (score 5):

That's the "bitwise and" operator.  Normally, it takes two integers, and returns an integer that has only the bits set that are in both of it's parameters.

```
base10 base2
6       0110
3       0011
6&3     0010   (=2)
```

There's also "bitwise or" `|` which sets bits that either one has set.

```
base10 base2
6       0110
3       0011
6|3     0111   (=7)
```

and there's "bitwise xor" `^` which sets bits that are different.

```
base10 base2
6       0110
3       0011
6^3     0101   (=5)
```

Comment: I think you mean `6&3`, `6|3` and `6^3`

Comment: @torrentialcoding: Thanks.  I started with 5 and 2, but then switched to more interesting numbers

Comment: Right. 6 and 3 better illustrate the bit operations.

Answer (score 2):

It's a bitwise AND operator. The value of n is being ANDed with 5.

Comment: It's bitwise, not logical operator.

Answer (score 2):

You were already told that in this case it's a binary and. But this requires a bit more explanation. In C and other C-like languages there are two `&` operators. One is **unary** the other **binary**.

A **unary** operator acts on a single value alone, while a **binary** operator takes in two values. In C **binary** operators take precedence over unary ones. If you write

```
int b;
int *a = &b;
```

Then `b` is the only value the operator can work on. If you write however

```
int c, d;
int d = c & d;
```

then the operator has two values to work with and the binary interpretation takes precedence over the unary interpretation. Note that this does not only apply to the `&` operator, but also its counterpart `*`

```
int *f;
int h = *f;
```

But also

```
int i,j;
int k = i * j;
```

Like with all operators, precedence can be overridden with parentheses:

```
int l, *m;
int n = l * (*m);
```